# I have plot p-value on boxplot using ggplot2 package. How to get pvalue in decimal format only

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

```
mydata <- read.csv(paste("plot.csv"), na.strings = c("", "NA"))
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
options(scipen=10L)
compare_means(XYZ ~ GR, data = mydata, method="wilcox.test")
my_comparisons<-list(c("A", "B"), 
                     c("A", "C"), 
                     c("B", "C"))
plotXYZ <- ggboxplot(mydata, x = "GR", y = "XYZ", color = "GR", palette = "jco", fill="GR"
                    )+ 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons=my_comparisons,label.y=c(120,150,160))+               
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 170)
plotXYZ
```

`I want pvalue between-group in decimal form  place of scientific

like I m getting pvalue 2.9e-05 . But I want 0.00029 to be print on plot

Answer (score 0):

I believe `options(scipen = n)` does not apply for plots. I see that you're already using `scales`. Have you tried this:

`plotXYZ + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)`